# Getting doubles with animated sprite in libgdx

Tags: libgdx

I am making a small simplistic game in libgdx to learn the basics and stuff. I tried my hand at having an animated character. One problem though, the first of the 4 frames shows fine but the second frame is shown and right next to it the third is rendered. The same for the third, it renders the last frame beside it. The first and last frame have no "Double" beside it though.

Character frames = C1 C2 C3 C4

1st frame - C1

2nd frame - C2 C3

3rd frame - C3 C4

4th frame(last) - C4

As for the code:

```
......
walk = new Animation(0.0015f, assets.leftframes);
.......
statetime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();                      
currentframe = walk.getKeyFrame(statetime, true);      
batcher.draw(currentframe, character.x, character.y);
.......
```

I left out rest of the code to reduce clutter but I can show it if necessary.

Does anyone have any idea what the problem is?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Terrible paint skills but here is the picture of each frame as rendered:

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zb42z.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your second and third frames width are double of what they should be.
Check when you create your animation, all keyframes must have same width.
And your time between frames is too fast, try 0.2F.

EDIT (because your comment):

Thats what is wrong, every new frame gets a bigger width.

Replace this:

```
leftframes[x] = new TextureRegion(left, x * 32, 0, (x+1) * 32, 48);
```

With this:

```
leftframes[x] = new TextureRegion(left, x * 32, 0, 32, 48);
```

Comment: i created the 4 different regions with a loop like leftframes[x] = new TextureRegion(left, x * 32, 0, (x+1) * 32, 48); so not sure how it would have twice the size though. If that was the case why wouldnt the first one have it too?

Comment: Thats what is wrong, every new frame gets a bigger width.

Replace this:

    leftframes[x] = new TextureRegion(left, x * 32, 0, (x+1) * 32, 48);

With this:

    leftframes[x] = new TextureRegion(left, x * 32, 0, 32, 48);

Comment: oh wow. Thanks, i thought that the third parameter is the actual pixel it needed to go to. It worked perfectly :D thanks again.